# How do I get resource path for Root Resource in ApiGateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to change cache settings in api gateway for GET/OPTIONS methods of root resource using terraform.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "root_get_method_settings" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.default.id
  stage_name  = terraform.workspace
  method_path = "<root resource path>/GET"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "INFO"
    caching_enabled = true
  }
}
```

I am getting issue on `method_path` argument since I couldn't figure out correct value for **<root resource path>**.

`method_path` for any other resources like **{proxy+}** resource looks like below:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "proxy_get_method_settings" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.default.id
  stage_name  = terraform.workspace
  method_path = "{proxy+}/GET"
 }
```

Comment: It should be just `/GET`? Have you tried with that?

Comment: yes I have tried `/GET` as well as `GET` . But both didn't work.

Comment: Do you get any specific errors? "didn't work" is not very specific and informative.

Comment: Also what is your `aws_api_gateway_method` for the GET that you want to apply settings for.

Comment: resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "root_options_method" { rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.default.id        resource_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.default.root_resource_id         http_method = "GET"  authorization = "NONE" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path is `"~1/GET"`. Below is full **working example**:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "MyDemoAPI" {
  name        = "MyDemoAPI"
  description = "This is my API for demonstration purposes"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "MyDemoMethod" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.root_resource_id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization = "NONE"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "test" {
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_integration.test]
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  stage_name  = "prod"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "test" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.root_resource_id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.MyDemoMethod.http_method
  type        = "MOCK"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "root_get_method_settings" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyDemoAPI.id
  stage_name  = "prod"
  method_path = "~1/GET"

  settings {
    metrics_enabled = true
    logging_level   = "INFO"
    caching_enabled = true
  }
  
  depends_on  = [aws_api_gateway_deployment.test]
}
```

Comment: @rrajgautam No problem. Glad it worked out:-)